# I need to change textbox.text into decimal value to sum up totals and display in message box. Using vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to figure out how to grab a value in a textbox (the price), that was put there with a temporary variable and an array, and change it into a decimal value so I can sum up the total sales and then sum up the total weight from another textbox using the same array.  I have been working with this for about 5 hours now, with my book and searching online sites and nothing is working.  I am stuck in the private sub purchase button procedure, (second from the bottom).  My total items counter is working, and I made the subTotal Decimal and totalWeightDecimal counters also, to make sure the message box was working, but I want to change that += 1 into the correct code, I just can't find it. I tried the parseing, but it was a no go.  Change textbox.textI included my entire code for someone to look at.  I know I have too many private variables, just waiting to figure everything out before I get rid of them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  All in all, on this entire program I have spent a minimum of 15 hours.  Thank you for your time and effort.

```
'Declare Item Structure.
Structure Item
    Dim upcString As String
    Dim nameString As String
    Dim descriptionString As String
    Dim weightString As String
    Dim priceDecimal As Decimal
End Structure

'Declare the ItemPrices Structure
Public Structure ItemPrices
    Dim itemdescriptionString As String
    Dim itempriceDecimal As Decimal
    Dim itemweightDecimal As Decimal
    Dim itemupcInteger As Integer
End Structure

Public Class lab7Form
    Private price1Decimal As Decimal
    Private subTotalDecimal As Decimal
    Private grandTotalDecimal As Decimal
    Private totalDecimal As Decimal
    Private totalItemsInteger As Integer
    Private MessageString As String
    Private totalWeightDecimal As Decimal

    Dim myItem As Item
    Private ItemPricesArray(3) As ItemPrices

    Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
        If MsgBox("Click Yes to Exit, Click No to Cancel", MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "You Decide") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            Me.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub clearButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles clearButton.Click
        'Clear the textbox values.
        upcTextBox.Text = ""
        descriptionTextBox.Text = ""
        weightTextBox.Text = ""
        priceTextBox.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub lab7Form_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Load my itemsListbox with the items for the user.
        itemsListBox.Items.Add("Notebook PC")
        itemsListBox.Items.Add("Deskjet Printer")
        itemsListBox.Items.Add("Color Ink Cartridge")
        itemsListBox.Items.Add("Black Ink Cartridge")

        'Load the ItemPricesArray values. 
        ItemPricesArray(0).itemdescriptionString = "Notebook PC"
        ItemPricesArray(1).itemdescriptionString = "Deskjet Printer"
        ItemPricesArray(2).itemdescriptionString = "Color Ink Cartridge"
        ItemPricesArray(3).itemdescriptionString = "Black Ink Cartridge"

        ItemPricesArray(0).itempriceDecimal = 1500D
        ItemPricesArray(1).itempriceDecimal = 430D
        ItemPricesArray(2).itempriceDecimal = 11D
        ItemPricesArray(3).itempriceDecimal = 10D

        ItemPricesArray(0).itemweightDecimal = 7D
        ItemPricesArray(1).itemweightDecimal = 16D
        ItemPricesArray(2).itemweightDecimal = 0.5D
        ItemPricesArray(3).itemweightDecimal = 0.5D

        ItemPricesArray(0).itemupcInteger = 111111111
        ItemPricesArray(1).itemupcInteger = 222222222
        ItemPricesArray(2).itemupcInteger = 333333333
        ItemPricesArray(3).itemupcInteger = 444444444
    End Sub

    Private Sub itemsListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles itemsListBox.SelectedIndexChanged
        descriptionTextBox.Text = itemsListBox.Text
        'I am using a table lookup   Do/Loop here.
        Dim myBoolean As Boolean        'True = I found an items price.
        Dim indexInteger As Integer = 0
        Do Until myBoolean Or indexInteger > 3
            With Me
                If .descriptionTextBox.Text = ItemPricesArray(indexInteger).itemdescriptionString Then
                    .priceTextBox.Text = ItemPricesArray(indexInteger).itempriceDecimal.ToString("C")
                    .weightTextBox.Text = ItemPricesArray(indexInteger).itemweightDecimal.ToString()
                    .upcTextBox.Text = ItemPricesArray(indexInteger).itemupcInteger.ToString()
                    myBoolean = True
                Else
                    indexInteger += 1
                End If
            End With
        Loop
    End Sub

    Private Sub purchaseButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles purchaseButton.Click
         Dim DecNumber1 As Decimal
        'Parse Numbers 
        DecNumber1 = Decimal.Parse(priceTextBox.Text)

        If purchaseButton.Enabled And priceTextBox.Text <> "" Then
            'Calculate the quantities
            totalItemsInteger += 1  'I can't figure out how to total up the weights and prices when they are both local variables.
            subTotalDecimal += DecNumber1
            totalWeightDecimal += 1

            'From Page 172 Put together what you want to appear in message boxes
            Dim MessageString As String
            Dim totalString As String
            Dim numberOfItemsString As String
            Dim weightOfItemsString As String

            numberOfItemsString = totalItemsInteger.ToString()
            totalString = subTotalDecimal.ToString("C")
            weightOfItemsString = totalWeightDecimal.ToString("N")

            MessageString = "Total Items : " & numberOfItemsString &
                Environment.NewLine & "Total Weight: " & weightOfItemsString &
                Environment.NewLine & "Subtotal: " & totalString

            'Display the message box
            MessageBox.Show(MessageString, "Items Purchased", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub totalButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles totalButton.Click
        Dim numberofOrdersString As String
        If totalButton.Enabled Then
            numberofOrdersString = "Number of Orders:  " & totalItemsInteger.ToString()
            MessageString = "Total Sales:  " & grandTotalDecimal.ToString("C")

            'Display the message box
            MessageBox.Show(MessageString, "Items Purchased", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What do you need the totalItemsInteger to calculate?

Comment: Please post / include the ItemPrices Class. (You'll need to Iterate through the Array to get the total.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over the array of `ItemPrices` objects, like this:

```
Dim itempriceDecimalTotal As Decimal
Dim itemweightDecimalTotal As Decimal

For Each theItemPrices As ItemPrices In ItemPricesArray
    itempriceDecimalTotal += theItemPrices.itempriceDecimal
    itemweightDecimalTotal += theItemPrices.itemweightDecimal
Next
```

Now you can convert the values to strings, like this:

```
Dim MessageString As String
Dim totalString As String
Dim numberOfItemsString As String
Dim weightOfItemsString As String

numberOfItemsString = totalItemsInteger.ToString()
totalString = itempriceDecimalTotal.ToString("C")
weightOfItemsString = itemweightDecimalTotal.ToString("N")
```

Finally, you can display the total values in a message box, like this:

```
MessageString = "Total Items : " & numberOfItemsString &
        Environment.NewLine & "Total Weight: " & weightOfItemsString &
        Environment.NewLine & "Subtotal: " & totalString

'Display the message box
MessageBox.Show(MessageString, "Items Purchased", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the total of any property of the items in the array is a simple matter of leveraging the LINQ extension method Sum:

```
Dim grandtotal As Double = ItemPricesArray.Sum(Function(x) x.itempriceDecimal)
```

Then displaying as a string works well with the ToString() method:

```
Textbox1.Text = grandtotal.ToString("C2")'display as currency with 2 decimal places
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim priceTotal As Double = (From itemPrice in ItemPricesArray
                            Select itemPrice.itempriceDecimal).Sum

Dim weightTotal As Double = (From itemPrice in ItemPricesArray
                             Select itemPrice.itemweightDecimal).Sum
```